# Many uncountable dense linear orders

Tags: model-theory

A theorem of Shelah (which has been quoted several times on this website) states that if $T$ is a countable unstable theory and $\kappa$ is an uncountable cardinal, then $T$ has $2^\kappa$ non-isomorphic models of cardinality $\kappa$.
I was wondering if there is an elementary way ($\mathit{i.e.}$ requiring very little model and set theory) to illustrate this theorem in the special case of dense linear orders. In particular, I would like to construct explicitly $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ pairwise non-isomorphic dense linear orders of cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$. My starting point was to consider the real line (“horizontally”) and to attach to every real number on the line a “vertical” fiber, which would be either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$, and then order the whole subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ obtained this way by the lexicographic order. Given any $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, I would then consider the dense linear order $\mathcal{M}_A$ which has $\mathbb{R}$ as a vertical fiber over every $x\in A$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ as a vertical fiber over every $x\notin A$. I have produced $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ models of cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$, which unfortunately are not pairwise non-isomorphic (for example, whenever $A$ and $B$ are singletons, $\mathcal{M}_A$ and $\mathcal{M}_B$ are isomorphic). So I'm not sure this is the way to go. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start with $\kappa$ and replace each ordinal with either $(\omega_1^*+\omega_1)\times \mathbb{Q}$ or $(1+\omega_1^*+\omega_1)\times \mathbb{Q}$. This gives $2^{\kappa}$ many nonisomorphic dense orders.

Comment: Hi, could you explain a bit more? Why do you need $(\omega_1^*+\omega_1)$ and not just $\omega_1$? Why the “$\times\mathbb{Q}$” bit? If I'm only interested in $\kappa = \mathfrak{c}$ could I replace $\kappa$ by $\mathbb{R}$ with its usual order or is it important that the “base” be well-ordered? I guess I don't see why any two such models are not isomorphic.

Comment: @R.Harlow 1. The basic point is that $\omega_1+1+\omega_1^*$ is not isomorphic to $\omega_1 + \omega_1^*$. In the first, the cut of uncountable cofinality is filled, and in the second it isn't. On the other hand, $\omega_1 + 1+\omega_1$ is isomorphic to $\omega_1 + \omega_1$, so the argument wouldn't work. 2. The $\times\mathbb{Q}$ is just there to make the order dense. 3. The base is taken to be well-ordered so that it's rigid. If you start with $\mathbb{R}$, you have the problem that the base order already has lots of automorphisms, which makes things more complicated.

Comment: 4. Let $O_1$ and $O_2$ be two orders constructed as above, and suppose they are isomorphic. The isomorphism establishes a bijection between the cuts of uncountable cofinality in $O_1$ and those in $O_2$. These cuts are ordered as $(\kappa,<)$, and $(\kappa,<)$ is rigid, so there is only one choice for the induced bijection on cuts. Hence a cut in $O_1$ is filled if and only if the corresponding cut in $O_2$ is filled, so $O_1$ and $O_2$ were constructed from the same subset of $\kappa$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thanks a lot for your explanations, I understand 2,3,4 and I still have a question about 1. Could you replace $\omega_1$ by $\omega$ everywhere in the argument? The $\kappa$ on the base takes care of the cardinality of the models and of the number of models, and point 1. seems to me to go through unchanged (the two “fibers” not being isomorphic).

Comment: @R.Harlow No, because for *any* two countable linear orders $L$ and $L'$, $L\times \mathbb{Q}$ and $L\times \mathbb{Q}$ are isomorphic (being countable dense linear orders).

Comment: No, this is where the uncountability assumption comes in. Remember you are replacing the ordinals by copies of the rational, so you need gaps of uncountable cofinality.

Comment: Of course. Thanks, both of you.

Comment: @AlexKruckman : I am trying to follow this interesting conversation, but I realize that I don't know what you mean by the "cofinality of a cut". Do you see a cut as a pair $(A,B)$, and consider the cofinality of $B$, or is it something else ?

Comment: @ratalan You can find the definitions at the beginning of [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72612/what-is-the-spectrum-of-possible-cofinality-types-for-cuts-in-an-ordered-field). I was being a bit sloppy with language - I should have referred to cuts of cofinality type $(\aleph_1,\aleph_1)$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman OK, thanks !

Comment: @AlexKruckman In your argument, are using the fact that $\left(\omega_1^{\ast}+ \omega_1\right)\times \mathbb{Q}$ and $\left(1+ \omega_1^{\ast}+ \omega_1\right) \times \mathbb{Q}$ are non-isomorphic?

Comment: @CuriousKid7 Essentially, yes, though I phrased it differently by talking about cuts.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I asked because I don't see why it's enough that a cut in $O_1$ is filled if and only if the corresponding cut in $O_2$ is filled. I suspect this has something to do with the orders I mentioned being non-isomorphic, but I'm not sure. Could you explain a bit?

Comment: @CuriousKid7 Is it not obvious that an isomorphism carries a filled cut to a filled cut? Suppose $f\colon O_1\to O_2$ is an isomorphism. If $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $O_1$, then there exists $x\in O_1$ with $A < x < B$ if and only if there exists $y\in O_2$ with $f(A) < y < f(B)$... (take $y = f(x)$ or conversely $x = f^{-1}(y)$).

Comment: @AlexKruckman Yes, that is obvious. I was asking why this is enough to conclude that $O_1$ and $O_2$ were constructed in the same way. Anyway, I think a better question  to clarify things for me is why are $\left(\omega_1^{\ast} + \omega_1\right)\times \mathbb{Q}$ and $\left(1+ \omega_1^{\ast} + \omega_1\right)\times \mathbb{Q}$ non-isomorphic? I understand your argument that $\left(\omega_1^{\ast} + \omega_1\right)$ and $\left(1+ \omega_1^{\ast} + \omega_1\right)$ are non-isomorphic, but I'm not sure it still works after adding $\times \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: The former has a suborder of order type $\omega_1^*$ with no lower bound. The latter does not.